# How to maximize $\| {\bf U x}\|^2$ when ${\bf U}$ is a upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, boundary-value-problem

When ${\bf U}$ is an $N$-by-$N$ complex-valued upper triangular matrix whose diagonal elements are positive real values, how to obtain an $N$-by-$1$ vector ${\bf x}=[x_1\cdots x_N]^T$ with $|x_n|=1$, for all $n=1,...,N$, that maximizes $\| {\bf U x}\|^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Lagrangian for Lagrange multipliers and take the gradient

$$f(\mathbf{x},\lambda) = \mathbf{x^TU^TUx}-\lambda(\mathbf{x^Tx}-1)$$

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}f = 2\mathbf{x^TU^TU}-2\lambda\mathbf{x^T} =0\implies \mathbf{U^TUx} = \lambda\mathbf{x}$$

In other words, the vectors that extremize the function $\mathbf{x^TU^TUx}$ on the constraint $\mathbf{x^Tx}-1=0$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{U^TU}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The constraint $|x_n|=1,\forall n$ is different from the constraint what you considered... Can you consider the constraint (absolute value of each element of ${\bf x}$ is one) to solve the maximization?

Comment: @HyunsJoung woops that is my fault for misreading. I don't think we can use Lagrange multipliers anymore than because this is a discrete constraint, which means I'm out of tools from my toolbox. I will delete my answer soon.

Comment: @NinadMunshi It's not actually discrete because OP is considering complex numbers.

Comment: Since the $x_i$ are complex numbers, the feasible region is an $n$-torus, so it should be possible to use standard variational tools.

Comment: @Ruy can you suggest any "standard variational tools" that you told to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!